# External link with crosswalk plugin

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm working on an ionic project with crosswalk plugin (cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview) version 1.6.1. When building my Android app for production, the external links don't work but work fine in development build on simulator and real device.

I have the following code:

```
<button class="button icon-left ion-radio-waves button-clear" ng-href="http://www.mywebsite.com" onclick="window.open(this.href, '_blank', 'location=no'); return false;"></button>
```

I can only imagine that crosswalk plugin is causing an issue here but not 100% sure.

Comment: have you got the `InAppBrowser` plugin?

Comment: Yes. cordova-plugin-inappbrowser version 1.2.1

Comment: alright there will be some error on the console that might help?

Comment: I ran `ionic build android`. I don’t get any errors, just few warnings and notes:

WARNING [Project: :] Current NDK support is deprecated.  Alternative will be provided in the future.

Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

Comment: The build command successfully produces android-armv7-debug.apk and 
android-x86-debug.apk files. The external links for armv7 apk work fine when installed on a real device but when I do `ionic package build android` and install on real device the external links dont work.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your question exactly, but be clear that InAppBrowser uses the default Android webview. The crosswalk plugin only applies to the main Cordova app. If you're trying to use crosswalk for external links, you'll need to make your own InAppBrowser-like plugin to leverage crosswalk.

InAppBrowser should still be able to coexist with a Cordova app using crosswalk though, so that won't be causing this error.